# How to make a slider image gallery without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a slider image gallery without using jquery. at the moment the slider works very nicely but the way i worked it is by having the images as a background, taking the full width of a div, this kind of looks weird on different devices. I want them to pop out of the page like a lightbox but without the use of jquery so that the images show with their normal width and height instead of being "covered" as a background to fill the div. I honestly couldn't find anything online so i'm posting this question here to see if anyone can help. Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

**I realize that the images don't actually show but that's because I don't know how to upload them on the snippet tool**

```js
// getting items from the DOM
const menuButton = document.querySelector(".menuButton");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const myPortrait = document.querySelector(".myPortrait");
const menuItems = document.querySelector(".menuItems");
const navItem = document.querySelectorAll(".navItem");
const menuWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".menuWrapper");
const photography = document.querySelector("#photography");

// Setting Initial State of Menue
let showMenu = false;

menuButton.addEventListener("click", openMenu);

function openMenu() {
  if (!showMenu) {
    menuButton.classList.add("close");
    menu.classList.add("show");
    menuWrapper.forEach(item => item.classList.add("show"));
    myPortrait.classList.add("show");
    menuItems.classList.add("show");
    navItem.forEach(item => item.classList.add("show"));
    photography.classList.add("show");

    //new menue state
    showMenu = true;
  } else {
    menuButton.classList.remove("close");
    menu.classList.remove("show");
    menuWrapper.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("show"));
    myPortrait.classList.remove("show");
    menuItems.classList.remove("show");
    navItem.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("show"));
    photography.classList.remove("show");

    //new menue state
    showMenu = false;
  }
}
//------------------------photography slide show---------------------------------
let slider = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
leftArrow = document.querySelector(".leftArrow");
rightArrow = document.querySelector(".rightArrow");
current = 0;

//clears images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
// starts slider
function startSlide() {
  reset();
  slider[0].style.display = "block";
}
// show slide left
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  slider[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}
// show slide right
function slideright() {
  reset();
  slider[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}
//left arrow click
leftArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = slider.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});
// right arrow click
rightArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === slider.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideright();
});
startSlide();
```

```css
/* main.css */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*---------BODY & BACKGROUND-----------*/
body {
  font-family: "Merienda";
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
footer {
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
/*---------HEADING & MAIN SCREEN STUFF-----------*/
#home {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9), rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9)),
    url("/Images/Iphonexbackground.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 20vh);
  padding-top: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-align: center;
}
.largeHeading {
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
}
.smallHeading {
  padding-bottom: 50vh;
}
.moe {
  color: white;
}
.social a {
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
}
.social a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*------------------ROTATING MENU BUTTON----------------------*/
.menuButton {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 35px;
  top: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.buttonLine {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.close > .buttonLine:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(405deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
.close > .buttonLine:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.close > .buttonLine:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-405deg) translate(5px, -5px);
}
/*------------------------------FULL MENU----------------------------*/
.menu {
  width: 100vh;
}
/*Menu is closed by default*/
.menuWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.show > .menuWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*----------------------PORTRAIT MENU-----------------------*/
/*handles image*/
.myPortrait {
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.show > .portrait {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url("/Images/Portrait.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  border: 3px solid rgb(200, 150, 15);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.show > .myPortrait {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*----------------------LINK MENU-----------------------*/
.navLink {
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.current > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.navItem a:hover {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.menuItems {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.navItem {
  transform: translate3d(600px, 0, 0);
}
/*handles menue items*/
.show > .menuItems {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  list-style: none;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*Delays each individual link movments
coming from the right side*/
.show > .navItem:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(8) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
  color: brown;
}

/*photography.css*/
#photography {
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 15vh);
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
.photoHeading {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.photoWork {
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.photoWork a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.gallary {
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.gallary img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.gallaryDiscription {
  padding: 2px;
}
.gallary:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1.015);
}
.photoSocial {
  padding: 10px;
}
.photoContainer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid white;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.slide1 {
  background-image: url("/Images/Photography/Animal/FullAnimal-1.jpg");
}
.slide2 {
  background-image: url("/Images/Photography/Animal/FullAnimal-2.jpg");
}
.slide3 {
  background-image: url("/Images/Photography/Animal/FullAnimal-3.jpg");
}
.show > .photoContainer > .arrow {
  display: none;
}
.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.leftArrow {
  border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) transparent transparent;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.rightArrow {
  border-width: 30px 0 40px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
/*
.showImage img {
  width: 100%;
}
.gridImage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(200px / 3);
}
.gridImage {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 33%);
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/photography.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/media.css" />
    <title>Mohamed Negm</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="menuButton">
        <div class="buttonLine"></div>
        <div class="buttonLine"></div>
        <div class="buttonLine"></div>
      </div>
      <nav class="menu">
        <div class="menuWrapper">
          <div class="myPortrait"><div class="portrait"></div></div>
          <ul class="menuItems">
            <li class="navItem"><a href="/" class="navLink">HOME </a></li>
            <li class="navItem">
              <a href="about.html" class="navLink">ABOUT ME </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navItem">
              <a href="contact.html" class="navLink">CONTACT </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navItem">
              <a href="animationPortfolio.html" class="navLink"
                >ANIMATION PORTFOLIO
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navItem">
              <a href="developerPortfolio.html" class="navLink"
                >DEVELOPER PORTFOLIO
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navItem">
              <a href="educatorPortfolio.html" class="navLink"
                >EDUCATOR PORTFOLIO
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navItem current">
              <a href="photographyPortfolio.html" class="navLink"
                >PHOTOGRAPHY PORTFOLIO
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navItem">
              <a href="videographyPortfolio.html" class="navLink"
                >VIDEOGRAPHY PORTFOLIO
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main id="photography">
      <a href="/Pages/photographyPortfolio.html" class="photoHeading"
        ><h1>PHOTOGRAPHY PORTFOLIO</h1></a
      >
      <div class="photoContainer">
        <div class="leftArrow arrow"></div>
        <div class="slide1 slide"></div>
        <div class="slide2 slide"></div>
        <div class="slide3 slide"></div>
        <div class="rightArrow arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="social photoSocial">
        <a
          href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohamed-negm-332299127/"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i
        ></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/moenegm" target="_blank">
          <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i
        ></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/moe_negm/" target="_blank">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i
        ></a>
        <a
          href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKZpp79IKpBMoG1C2Ufrmgw?view_as=subscriber"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i
        ></a>
        <a
          href="https://www.facebook.com/Moeanegm?ref=bookmarks"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i
        ></a>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>Copyright &copy; 2019</footer>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ask me any clarifying questions you may have. With respect, last time I posted a question it was voted down without any comments. This makes me really afraid to ask any more questions. I'm here to learn. Thank you!

Comment: if you would like to see the slider in action with the actual images to get a better understanding go here: https://moenegm.ga/Pages/PhotographyGalleries/animal.html

Comment: @Mohammed , are you trying to zoom out image on image slide ??

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WLYVGR  , created codepen with sample images

Comment: Thank you for your help sir, I'm essentially trying to achieve  a lightbox gallery but without the use of jquery for example the one in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1B1Fx3XKOg&t=488s or just take a look at this picture: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pxx6VPDFjMPq8Ht89 so that the images pop out with their regular width and height rather than being stretched to fit the div.

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea to make Image slideshow using Only Bootstrap which is MOBILE responsive too, if you don't wanted to use JQuery. Here is Bootstrap Carousel Plugin check this link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all you're help. I figured out the issue:
I did this in the html:

```
<div class="slide2 slide"></div>
```

then did this in the css:

```
.slide2 {
  background-image: url("/Images/Photography/Animal/FullAnimal-2.jpg");
}
```

this made the image strech to fit the div instead i tried adding the images in the html directly without a div like so:

```
<img
          src="/Images/Photography/Animal/FullAnimal-1.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="slide1 slide"
        />
```

and took away the height:100% from the css like so:

```
.photoContainer {
  width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

this makes the image takes in it's full width and height regardless of the screen size. all I got to do now is use align the image vertically so that it's always in the center of the page. 
**thanks again for all your help, this mystery is solved!**

Comment: If anyone is interested in seeing the final fixed results it can be found here: https://moenegm.ga/Pages/PhotographyGalleries/animal.html you can inspect the page to see how the image re-sizes and still still keeps it's original width to height ratio.